# How to conditionally show and hide a tab?

Tags: r, shiny, tabs

I am trying to display within a `shiny` app the content of a `tabsetPanel` based on the response given to an initial  `checkboxGroupInput`.

[image]

The `showTab` and `hideTab` seems to be the right function for it: https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.3.1/showtab.

I do not get why the below reprex does not work.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(
    inputId =  "poptype",
    label = "Select Pop",
    choices = c("Pop1" = "RAS",
                "Pop2" = "STA"),
    selected = c("RAS")
  ),
  tabsetPanel(
    type = "tabs",
    tabPanel(title = "Pillar-1",
             "1 bla bla bla"),
    tabPanel(title = "Pillar-2",
             "2 bla bla bla")
  ) ## End Tabset
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  AppReactiveValue <-  reactiveValues(poptype = NULL,
                                      show_ras = FALSE,
                                      show_sta = FALSE)
  ## Based on selection, set flag to show or hide tab..
  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$poptype, {
    AppReactiveValue$poptype <- input$poptype
    if (any(input$poptype %in% c("RAS"))) {
      AppReactiveValue$show_ras <- TRUE
    } else  if (any(!(input$poptype %in% c("RAS"))))  {
      AppReactiveValue$show_ras <- FALSE
    }

    if (any(input$poptype %in% c("STA")))  {
      AppReactiveValue$show_sta <- TRUE
    } else if (any(!(input$poptype %in% c("STA"))))  {
      AppReactiveValue$show_sta <- FALSE
    }
  })
  ## Display conditionally....
  observeEvent(AppReactiveValue$show_ras, {

    #browser()
    if (isTRUE(AppReactiveValue$show_ras)) {
      showTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "Pillar-1")
    } else {
      hideTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "Pillar-1")
    }
  })
  observeEvent(AppReactiveValue$show_sta, {
    if (isTRUE(AppReactiveValue$show_sta)) {
      showTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "Pillar-2")
    } else {
      hideTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "Pillar-2")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I believe you have to include `session` explicitly in `showTab` and similar functions, like this: `showTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "Pillar-2", session = session)`

Comment: @BastiánOleaHerrera - tried - not working..

Comment: Adapting example from https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/shiny/html/showTab.html, the issue is when not using `navbarPage`  

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("hideTab", "Hide 'Foo' tab"), actionButton("showTab", "Show 'Foo' tab")
  tabsetPanel(  type = "tabs", tabPanel("Foo", "This is the foo tab"), tabPanel("Bar", "This is the bar tab"))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$hideTab, { hideTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "Foo")})
  observeEvent(input$showTab, { showTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "Foo")}) }
shinyApp(ui, server)  
```

Comment: In  tabPanel() you have set a title, but need to set a value too. From documentation: The value that should be sent when tabsetPanel reports that this tab is selected. If omitted and tabsetPanel has an id, then the title will be used.

Comment: @SusanSwitzer tried this below - is that what you meant... (does not work..) I understood that part of the doc, that title is automatically mapped to value..
  
  tabsetPanel(
    type = "tabs",
    tabPanel(title = "Pillar-1",
             value = "Pillar-1",
             "1 bla bla bla"),
    tabPanel(title = "Pillar-2",
             value = "Pillar-1",
             "2 bla bla bla")
  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `showTab` and `hideTab` you are referencing `inputId = "tabs"` but this is not defined inside your `ui`. You have to add it to your `tabsetPanel` and it should work.

```
tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabs",
        ...
```

[image]

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput(
        inputId =  "poptype",
        label = "Select Pop",
        choices = c("Pop1" = "RAS",
                    "Pop2" = "STA"),
        selected = c("RAS")
    ),
    tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabs",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel(title = "Pillar-1",
                 "1 bla bla bla"),
        tabPanel(title = "Pillar-2",
                 "2 bla bla bla")
    ) ## End Tabset
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    AppReactiveValue <-  reactiveValues(poptype = NULL,
                                        show_ras = FALSE,
                                        show_sta = FALSE)
    ## Based on selection, set flag to show or hide tab..
    observeEvent(eventExpr = input$poptype, {
        AppReactiveValue$poptype <- input$poptype
        if (any(input$poptype %in% c("RAS"))) {
            AppReactiveValue$show_ras <- TRUE
        } else  if (any(!(input$poptype %in% c("RAS"))))  {
            AppReactiveValue$show_ras <- FALSE
        }
        
        if (any(input$poptype %in% c("STA")))  {
            AppReactiveValue$show_sta <- TRUE
        } else if (any(!(input$poptype %in% c("STA"))))  {
            AppReactiveValue$show_sta <- FALSE
        }
    })
    ## Display conditionally....
    observeEvent(AppReactiveValue$show_ras, {
        
        print(AppReactiveValue$show_ras)
        #browser()
        if (AppReactiveValue$show_ras) {
            showTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "Pillar-1")
        } else {
            hideTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "Pillar-1")
        }
    })
    observeEvent(AppReactiveValue$show_sta, {
        if (isTRUE(AppReactiveValue$show_sta)) {
            showTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "Pillar-2")
        } else {
            hideTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "Pillar-2")
        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```